# How to read environment variables in .NET 6?

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-6.0

in my .NET Core 3.1 WebApi project I'm reading environment variable as the very first thing and loading appsettings.json according to it:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
{
  string environment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
  ...
}
```

But I didn't find out how to read it in .NET 6:

`var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);`

build.Environment has no way to read it.
Anyone knows?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The official documentation says that the method in the System namespace should work:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getenvironmentvariable?view=net-6.0

Comment: Any ideas on variable groups e.g. `builder.Services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(configuration.GetSection("AzureAdB2C"));`?

Answer (score 13):

I want to extend [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70024643/3025856) a bit, since it only references a link.

It is also possible to read environment variables into strongly typed configuration classes.

I.e., take a look at this class:

```cs
public class MyConfig
{
  public string ValueA { get; set; }
  public int ValueB { get; set; }
}
```

Let's also assume there are environment variables set to `MySection__ValueA` and `MySection__ValueB`.

If you register a config class as:

```cs
services.Configure<MyConfig>("MySection");
```

Then you will be able to access the configuration values in the code as:

```cs
public class SomeService
{
  public SomeService(IOptions<MyConfig> config)
  {
    // Here config.Value.ValueA is equal to MySection__ValueA
    // and config.Value.ValueB is equal to MySection__ValueB (automatically converted to int)
  }
```

Comment: And remember - whenever you add, remove, update environment variable you have to close and reopen VS. Otherwise your changes won't be reflected in loaded configuration. This will save you a lot of headache ;)